# Styling footer links with columns

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm currently working on a styled footer with three columns and links inside them. Everything works fine beside the copyright line which I'd like to put underneath the three columns. Problem: it sticks next to the third column and doesn't move down. I tried to do this with some nbsp; and p and br tag hacks. This works fine on desktop but looks bad on mobile devices. I want this responsive. Do you guys know how to put the copyright line aligned left underneath the three columns responsively? Thanks for any help.

This is what I got so far. (here's a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/hLLfrcwo/)

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
footer{
 height: auto;
 padding:1px 15px;
 width:auto;
 }
#footer_info_tab{
 float:left;
 width:auto;  
 padding:10px;
}
#footer_resources_tab{
 width:auto;;       
 float:left;
 text-align:justify;
 padding:10px;
 }
#footer_recommend_tab{
float: left;
width:auto;
text-align: justify; 
padding:10px;
}

</style>

<footer>
  <div id="footer_info_tab"><b>Info</b><p>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br></div>
  <div id="footer_resources_tab"><b>Resources</b><p>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br></div>
  <div id="footer_recommend_tab"><b>We Recommend</b><p>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br></div>
  <p><br>&nbsp;<p><br>&nbsp;<p><br>&nbsp;<br>&#x24B8;&nbsp;2011-2017 Company. All rights reserved.
</footer>
```

Comment: Resize the window to smartphone size and see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `clear: left;` for copyright paragraph to go below left aligned elements.